# How to make the jQuery slider only slide when dragging the handlers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, draggable

I'm trying to use a multiple handlers slide like jQuery example, but I what to be able to drag the part between the handlers.

jQuery example:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [prototyped](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/draggable-range-in-slider) by [davidpadbury](http://github.com/davidpadbury/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js).

If you want to do it manually, register a custom handler to the [slide event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide) and set the value of the handlers by accessing them like this:

```
$('#slide-id').slider('value', index);
```

Check the source of the [range slider example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range), this can be implemented similar to the setting of the dollar values in that example. However, this will only work easily if you want to have a permanently fixed range (i.e. losing the ability to adjust the range by the handlers). If you want to preserve that feature, check the implementation by David Padbury.

Comment: Prototyped code is currently not working with latest version of jquery.ui.slider! Is there any new fixes for the same?